# Writing mini program using break, and if statements in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, break

I'm a beginner in coding but extremely motivated and determined to learn. I was writing mini programs in Python 3 to play around with my understanding for if, and break statements. In the program I have written below, even when I put my answer as `Yes` it still prints `I'm sorry, I must've misheard you sir, my apologies`. On top of that, when I add `break` to the end of the `else`, it tells me it's out of the loop. I want to add `break` so if I do say `No` the program can stop. Can someone please explain ?

```
name = str(input('What is your name? '))
wrongname = input('Are you really ' + name + '?')
if wrongname != 'Yes':
    print("I'm sorry, I must've misheard you sir, my apologies")
else:
    print('I heard all about you Mr. ' + name + '!')  
input('What are you doing in town?')
input('Ah I see, well, I hope you enjoy your stay !')
print('Thank you !')
```

Comment: 1) Try adding a `print(wrongname)` and `print(wrongname == 'Yes') to see what the value being read in is and whether your sanity check is correct. 2) I'd recommend looking up the documentation for what `break` does before assuming you can just add it into your program. To achieve what you want you can move all the remaining `input` (what are you doing in town, etc) to right below `'I heard all about you Mr. ' + name + '!'`

Comment: Replace `if wrongname != 'Yes':` with if wrongname.upper() != 'YES': for more acceptable variations of yes

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_break_statement.htm

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not answering exactly `Yes` but something slightly different, e.g. `yes`.

To make it case-insensitive you could use, e.g.:

```
if wrongname.lower() != 'yes':
```

(or other similar variations).

Also note that there is currently no loop in the code, so it is a bit vague discussing about *breaking* from a loop at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```py
import sys

name = str(input('What is your name? '))
wrongname = input('Are you really ' + name + '?')
if wrongname == 'No':
    print('Exiting program')
    sys.exit(0)
if wrongname != 'Yes':
    print("I'm sorry, I must've misheard you sir, my apologies")
else:
    print('I heard all about you Mr. ' + name + '!')  
input('What are you doing in town?')
input('Ah I see, well, I hope you enjoy your stay !')
print('Thank you !')
```